# Why is this jQuery code affecting the parent?

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm built nested collapsible divs (Bootstrap) with 3 levels: `dist`, `admin`, and `agent`:

**HTML:**

```
  <div id="dists" class="list-container">
    <div class="dist" ng-repeat="dist in dists track by $index">
      <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#admins-{{$index + 1}}" ng-click="updatePanels()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;
        <span class="user-name"><strong>{{dist.realname}}</strong></span>
      </a>
      <div id="admins-{{$index + 1}}" class="list-container collapse">
        <div class="admin" ng-repeat="admin in dist.admins track by $index">
          <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#agents-{{$index + 1}}" ng-click="updatePanels()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>&nbsp;
          </a>
          <div id="agents-{{$index + 1}}" class="list-container collapse">
            <div class="agent" ng-repeat="agent in admin.agents track by $index">
              <a href="javascript:;">
              <span class="user-name"><strong>{{agent.realname}}</strong></span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**JS:**

```
  $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).parent()
      .find("a:first .glyphicon-plus")
      .removeClass("glyphicon-plus")
      .addClass("glyphicon-minus")
      event.stopPropagation()
  }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).parent()
      .find("a:first .glyphicon-minus")
      .removeClass("glyphicon-minus")
      .addClass("glyphicon-plus")
      event.stopPropagation()
  })
```

The divs, `.collapse`, have a plus sign. When you click them they show a minus sign:

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

3.

[image]

Works fine. The problem arises when you collapse an item:

4.

[image]

For some reason, the parent also changes it's sign. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

**EDIT** (Spencer's suggestion):

```
$scope.updatePanels = function($event) {
  $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).parent()
      .find("a:first .glyphicon-plus")
      .removeClass("glyphicon-plus")
      .addClass("glyphicon-minus")
    event.stopPropagation()
  }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function() {
    $(this).parent()
      .find("a:first .glyphicon-minus")
      .removeClass("glyphicon-minus")
      .addClass("glyphicon-plus")
    event.stopPropagation()
  }
```

Comment: Are you using angular? Also it could be that the event is propagating up to the parent, did you try adding `event.stopPropagation()`?

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek Yes, I'm using angular. Good eye! No, I haven't seen that stop propagation thing before. Could you give me an example of how to use it in in my code?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Hey it worked! (I placed them inside each `.collapse on` Could you post this as an answer?

Comment: Great, I've added the answer below, for browser compatibility you can access the `event` through the `function(e)`, where `e => event`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the events are propagating up to the parent, an event that goes off inside a child DOM element can also bubble up to the parent, calling the parent event as well. To stop this from happening you can add [`event.stopPropagation()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/).

```
  $('.collapse').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent()
      .find("a:first .glyphicon-plus")
      .removeClass("glyphicon-plus")
      .addClass("glyphicon-minus")
  }).on('hidden.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).parent()
      .find("a:first .glyphicon-minus")
      .removeClass("glyphicon-minus")
      .addClass("glyphicon-plus")
  })
```

Comment: @alexchenco Odd, for both or either `'shown.bs.collapse'` or `'hidden.bs.collapse'`? Would you mind placing you example as a fiddle?

Comment: Oh, no, false alarm. I mistakely placed the `e` in the outer function. Duh!